# Unification & Substitution

Tags: haskell, substitution, unification

In Haskell, I have defined a polymorphic data type `Subst a` with a single constructor `S :: [(String, a)] -> Subst a` as so:

```
data Subst a where
    S :: [(String, a)] -> Subst a
    deriving (Show)
```

I want to define a function `get::String -> Subst a -> Maybe a` that takes a variable name and a substitution, and returns the value for which that variable must be substituted. If the substitution is not defined on the variable, the function should return Nothing.

I've tried the following:

```
get :: String -> Subst a -> Maybe a
get str (S[]) = Nothing
get str (S((a,b):xs)) = if str == a then Just b
    else get str xs
```

But I'm getting errors. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have any reason for using the GADT syntax? Couldn't you write your type more easily as `data Subst a = S [(String, a)] deriving Show`?

Comment: @Tikhon no reason in particular actually, I was trying both ways as a learning mechanism to see if its different

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Map String a` instead of `[(String,a)]`. Lookups for lists take _O(n)_ while lookups for [maps](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-Map.html) take _O(log n)_.

Comment: +1 for @PetrPudlák suggestion. Even if you don't care about performance, the `Map a b` type has a very rich API for lookups and insertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get str (S((a,b):xs)) = if str == a then Just b
    else get str xs
```

`xs` is a list of type `[(String, a)]`, but the second argument of `get` must be a `Subst a`. It would work if you used a constructor to construct a value of the correct type,

```
get str (S((a,b):xs)) = if str == a then Just b
    else get str (S xs)
```

but it is simpler to use the list directly to look up the variable,

```
Prelude> :t lookup
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

so

```
get str (S xs) = lookup str xs
```

does exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks! I was originally using the lookup function but it was throwing me errors so I attempted to write my own but thanks for clearing this up!